# Strike down the 2-stroke tag (and 4-stroke)

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Duplicate tags: [2-stroke](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2-stroke) and [two-stroke](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/two-stroke)

**Edit:**  Also [4-stroke](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/4-stroke) and [four-stroke](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/four-stroke)

[two-stroke](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/two-stroke) has 1 follower and 22 questions, and [2-stroke](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2-stroke) has no followers, and 9 questions.  They seem to be pretty obviously the same thing.

I think we should go with [two-stroke](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/two-stroke), as it is (slightly) more common. Also, (IMO) it flows a little better. The same would also go for [4-stroke](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/4-stroke) and [four-stroke](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/four-stroke), although which one is again completely aesthetics.

Comment: I have moved all questions under the [tag:two-stroke] and [tag:four-stroke] tags. Now if we can get one of our two illustrious mods to make the synonyms. I'll leave a note in chat.

Comment: Hadn't realized I was the only follower of [two-stroke]. Glad I helped sway the decision :P

Answer (score 4):

They are basically the same thing. IMHO, it should probably go under [2-stroke](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2-stroke) just because I think it looks better (complete aesthetics here - Really it doesn't matter). It definitely should be consolidated, either way. There is also [4-stroke](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/4-stroke) and [four-stroke](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/four-stroke) ... either one could go either way. The real question is, since you brought it up, which way should it go? Edit your idea in your question and we'll tag @BobCross or @Movemorecommentslinktotop to come do the deed, since we don't have enough people in either tag to vote on making them a synonym.

Comment: Done ☺ I would personally go for completely written out, as that's a little more common.

Answer (score 3):

I agree. Most style guides I've seen say that you should spell out numbers under 10 (e.g. [This Academia.SE question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/27934/when-and-why-should-you-write-numbers-less-than-10-in-words), so on that basis it ought to be [four-stroke](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/four-stroke) and [two-stroke](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/two-stroke)

Answer (score 0):

For symmetry should the `rotary-engine` tag be changed to `rotary`?

And how did you get the nice rounded tag highlights? I'm not allowed to inspect by editing…

Comment: This looks like it should be a separate question...

Comment: Which part (or both)?

Comment: Well, mainly the first part- I think you get the nice rounded tag by linking to the tag. (but I'm not sure)

Comment: Actually, its `[tag:tag-name]` & `[meta-tag:tag-name]`  per http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69482/258851

Comment: And now that you've asked the separate question, you can probably delete this one.